# .change() doesn't work in Chrome when using autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

.change() event doesn't work in Chrome when using autocomplete script and work when enter another value doesn't exist in autocomplete ...
but my code is totally working fine in Firefox

my code as the below

```
    $('body').on('change', 'input[name^="itemNo"]', function(){

    var currentquantity = $(this).val();
    var maxquantity = $(this).data('maxquant');

    alert(currentquantity);
    alert(maxquantity);

    })
```

and my html code as the below

```
<input type="text" data-type="product_serial" name="itemNo[]" data-maxquant="" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt serial_number_append" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in Chrome? Can you reproduce the problem with a jsFiddle?

Comment: jQuery UI autocomeplete has it's own  [`change` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change). Have you tried it?

Comment: no error appeared ,, the event is working fine if i don't use the autocomplete

Comment: @Vohuman i tried the above code only,, do you have a good idea to make this code works fine with Chrome

Comment: Can you upload your working code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Looks like a perfectly valid question to me, and I did hit the same issue (solved by an answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Use the autocomplete's change event. You can bind it using the 'autocompletechange' event:

```
$('input[name^="itemNo"]').on( "autocompletechange", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

or on initialization, as in the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp"
  ];
  $('input[name^="itemNo"]').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  }, {
    change: function(event, ui) {
      var currentquantity = $(this).val();
      var maxquantity = $(this).data('maxquant');

      alert(currentquantity);
      alert(maxquantity);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js "></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="text " data-type="product_serial " name="itemNo[] " data-maxquant=" " id="itemNo_1 " class="form-control autocomplete_txt serial_number_append " autocomplete="off ">
```

See documentation for further information: [autocomplete API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)

Comment: No problem, please set it as an accepted answer if it answers your question, for everyone's benefit. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

This works for me in chrome. The change event is called when the input field loses focus

```js
$('body').on('change', 'input[name^="itemNo"]', function(){

    var currentquantity = $(this).val();
    var maxquantity = $(this).data('maxquant');

    alert(currentquantity);
    alert(maxquantity);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-type="product_serial" name="itemNo[]" data-maxquant="" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt serial_number_append" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: @jackson you are right in this case the code is working fine but when using the autocomplete the code doesn't work